# Customer to be called means?

Tags: meaning

My courier service provided updated the status as "Customer to be called". What does that means? Should I need to call them or they will call me?

Comment: Note:- You should write,  "What does that ***mean***". The auxiliary verb "to do" requires a bare infinitive. –  chasly from UK 11 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

It is the **passive infinitive**.

The customer is **to be called** by the courier/courier service.

> **Note:** If you the customer are required call them, then it would be, "Customer to call."

Comment: Other way around, I'd wager. (S)he is the costumer, and the status on his courier delivery is now that they (the courier service provider) have to call him/her.

Comment: @JBJ Thanks. You win your wager, so +1 from me as your winnings!  I read the first line too quickly. I have amended my answer.